# Select2 .val select option not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 (version 4.0.5) and can't get the .val method to work. 
noted here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items 
Perhaps I'm adding too early, can anyone help?

I define a php variable (from page URL) 
eg from:  example.com/?searchTextField=Somewhere1

```
<?php $LocationSearchTextField = $this->getRequest()->getParam('searchTextField'); ?>
```

then Select2 is initialized:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.select2-select').select2({
    theme: "classic",
    allowClear: true
 });
 $('.select2-select').val('"<?php echo $LocationSearchTextField ?>"');
 $('.select2-select').trigger('change');
 });
</script>
```

The select options are then defined here:

```
<select class="select2-select searchpage" id="searchTextField" name="searchTextField" data-minimumResultsForSearch="-1" data-placeholder="Location.." />
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Places1">
        <option value="Somewhere1">Somewhere1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Places2">
        <option value="Somewhere2">Somewhere2</option>
        <option value="Somewhere3">Somewhere3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

But Select2 uses the Placeholder, and does not observe the .val option.

How can I tell Select2 to use the $LocationSearchTextField variable as the Selected value (while allowing clear to Placeholder) ?

Comment: It would be more useful to show the *served* javascript, with the actual value not some php expression.

Comment: You're inserting both types of quotes as `val`. You only need one type.  https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3k82zacq/ Edit: Just found another typo, you're self closing the `<select>`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG !

Fixed it.
1. Removed the closing / 
and
2. Had to change this:
    $('.select2-select').val('"<?php echo $LocationSearchTextField ?>"');
to this:$('.select2-select').val('<?php echo $LocationSearchTextField ?>');

Now working great. Thanks for the second set of eyes, and the Fiddle

Comment: But can't accept your answer, not enough rep